# How do I perform arbitrary calculations on groups of records in a Spark dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe like this:

```
|-----+-----+-------+---------|
| foo | bar | fox   | cow     |
|-----+-----+-------+---------|
|   1 |   2 | red   | blue    | // row 0
|   1 |   2 | red   | yellow  | // row 1
|   2 |   2 | brown | green   | // row 2
|   3 |   4 | taupe | fuschia | // row 3
|   3 |   4 | red   | orange  | // row 4
|-----+-----+-------+---------|
```

I need to group the records by "foo" and "bar" and then perform some magical computation on "fox" and "cow" to produce "badger", which may insert or delete records:

```
|-----+-----+-------+---------+---------|
| foo | bar | fox   | cow     | badger  |
|-----+-----+-------+---------+---------|
|   1 |   2 | red   | blue    | zebra   |
|   1 |   2 | red   | blue    | chicken |
|   1 |   2 | red   | yellow  | cougar  |
|   2 |   2 | brown | green   | duck    |
|   3 |   4 | red   | orange  | peacock |
|-----+-----+-------+---------+---------|
```

(In this example, row 0 has been split into two "badger" values, and row 3 has been deleted from the final output.)

My best approach so far looks like this:

```
val groups = df.select("foo", "bar").distinct
groups.flatMap(row => {
  val (foo, bar): (String, String) = (row(0), row(1))
  val group: DataFrame = df.where(s"foo == '$foo' AND bar == '$bar'")
  val rowsWithBadgers: List[Row] = makeBadgersFor(group)
  rowsWithBadgers
})
```

This approach has a few problems:

1. It's clumsy to match on `foo` and `bar` individually. (A utility method can clean that up, so not a big deal.)
2. It throws an `Invalid tree: null\nnull` error because of the nested operation in which I try to refer to `df` from inside `groups.flatMap`. Don't know how to get around that one yet.
3. I'm not sure whether this mapping and filtering actually leverages Spark distributed computation correctly.

Is there a more performant and/or elegant approach to this problem?

This question is very similar to [Spark DataFrame: operate on groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30354964/spark-dataframe-operate-on-groups), but I'm including it here because 1) it's not clear if that question requires addition and deletion of records, and 2) the answers in that question are out-of-date and lacking detail.

I don't see a way to accomplish this with `groupBy` and a [user-defined aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32100973/how-to-define-and-use-a-user-defined-aggregate-function-in-spark-sql), because an aggregation function aggregates to a single row. In other words,

```
udf(<records with foo == 'foo' && bar == 'bar'>) => [foo,bar,aggregatedValue]
```

I need to possibly return **two or more different rows, or zero rows** after analyzing my group. I don't see a way for aggregation functions to do this -- if you have an example, please share.

Comment: @user9613318 - I updated to question to clarify why I don't think an aggregation function works here. (That was the first thing I tried). Please  see if you agree.

Comment: can you share the logic of the expected dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

A user-defined function could be used.
The single row returned can contain a list.
Then you can explode the list into multiple rows and reconstruct the columns.

The aggregator:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator

case class StuffIn(foo: BigInt, bar: BigInt, fox: String, cow: String)
case class StuffOut(foo: BigInt, bar: BigInt, fox: String, cow: String, badger: String)
object StuffOut {
  def apply(stuffIn: StuffIn): StuffOut = new StuffOut(stuffIn.foo, 
stuffIn.bar, stuffIn.fox, stuffIn.cow, "dummy")
}

object MultiLineAggregator extends Aggregator[StuffIn, Seq[StuffOut], Seq[StuffOut]] {
  def zero: Seq[StuffOut] = Seq[StuffOut]()
  def reduce(buffer: Seq[StuffOut], stuff: StuffIn): Seq[StuffOut] = {
    makeBadgersForDummy(buffer, stuff)
  }

  def merge(b1: Seq[StuffOut], b2: Seq[StuffOut]): Seq[StuffOut] = {
    b1 ++: b2
  }
  def finish(reduction: Seq[StuffOut]): Seq[StuffOut] = reduction
  def bufferEncoder: Encoder[Seq[StuffOut]] = kryo[Seq[StuffOut]]
  def outputEncoder: Encoder[Seq[StuffOut]] = kryo[Seq[StuffOut]]
}
```

The call:

```
val averageSalary: TypedColumn[StuffIn, Seq[StuffOut]] = MultiLineAggregator.toColumn

val res: DataFrame =
  ds.groupByKey(x => (x.foo, x.bar))
          .agg(averageSalary)
          .map(_._2)
          .withColumn("value", explode($"value"))
          .withColumn("foo", $"value.foo")
          .withColumn("bar", $"value.bar")
          .withColumn("fox", $"value.fox")
          .withColumn("cow", $"value.cow")
          .withColumn("badger", $"value.badger")
          .drop("value")
```